# Why is my R code getting messed up when I execute it in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am running VS Code in a conda environment, and when I execute the following R code

```
library(NanoStringNCTools)
library(GeomxTools)
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr) # For tables.
library(ggforce)
library(scales) # For percents.
library(reshape2) # For melt.
library(cowplot) # For plot_grid.
library(umap)
library(Rtsne)

# File paths.
project_name <- "DSP-014"
prime_tr <- "~/OneDrive/Projects/"
wd <- paste0(prime_tr, project_name, "/")
setwd(wd)
common_dir <- paste0(prime_tr, "Common/")
# Data.
data_dir <- paste0(wd, "data/")
data_dir_raw <- paste0(data_dir, "raw_data/")
data_dir_processed <- paste0(data_dir, "processed_data/")
data_dir_processed_GeoMx <- paste0(data_dir_processed, "GeoMx/")
metadata_dir <- paste0(data_dir, "metadata/")
# Output
output_dir <- paste0(wd, "output/")
output_dir_rdata <- paste0(output_dir, "Rdata/")
output_dir_figures <- paste0(output_dir, "figures/")
output_dir_figures_qc <- paste0(output_dir_figures, "QC/")
output_dir_tabular <- paste0(output_dir, "tabular/")
output_dir_wgs <- paste0(output_dir, "WGS/")
# Experiment-specific variables.
phenodata_sheet_name <- "12182023_Appendix samples_20240"
phenodata_dcc_col_name <- "Sample_ID"
protocol_data_col_names <- c("Aoi", "Roi")
experiment_data_col_names <- c("Panel")
random_seed <- 1026
```

the code executes correctly until the section under `# Experiment-specific variables`, where I get the following output in the terminal window:

```
> # Experiment-specific variables.
> phphphphphphphphphme <- "12182023_Appendix samples_20240"
> phenodata_dcc_col_name <- "Sample_ID"
> protocol_data_col_namesprotocol_data_col")
+ experiment_data_col_names <- c("Panel")
Error: unexpected string constant in:
"protocol_data_col_namesprotocol_data_col")
experiment_data_col_names <- c(""
> random_seed <- 1026
```

What the heck is going on? Why is VS Code messing up my code like this? (Note how it’s turning the variable that’s `phenodata_sheet_name` in my code into `phphphphphphphphphme`.)

Further information: I am working on a 2021 16-inch Macbook Pro, Apple M1 Max chip, macOS Ventura 13.6.4. Miniconda: Apple M1 64-bit package downloaded from https://docs.anaconda.com/free/miniconda/miniconda-other-installer-links/, Python version 3.11.
YAML file used to build conda environment:

```
name: geomx
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
  - R
dependencies: 
  - conda-forge::r-base=4.3.1
  - conda-forge::r-tidyverse=2.0.0
  - conda-forge::r-dplyr=1.1.3
  - bioconda::bioconductor-nanostringnctools=1.10.0 
  - bioconda::bioconductor-geomxtools=3.5.0
  - conda-forge::r-knitr=1.45
  - conda-forge::r-ggforce=0.4.2
  - conda-forge::r-scales=1.3.0
  - conda-forge::r-reshape2=1.4.4
  - conda-forge::r-cowplot=1.1.3
  - conda-forge::r-umap=0.2.10.0
  - conda-forge::r-rtsne=0.17
```

I’ve uninstalled and re-installed VS Code, disabled R > Lsp: Diagnostics in VS Code, none of that works. Interestingly, every time I quit VS Code and re-run the code I get a different error.

Comment: My guess is that it's something to do with the terminal you're using. I have an older MBP and have also run into some weird issues with the term. If I run radian as the R terminal https://github.com/randy3k/radian I don't have things like that happen. But, if you're already using radian, making sure the bracketed paste is on might fix it. What's funny is that for me, I have to use the base R term when using Windows as radian refuses to work properly and on Mac I have to use radian or I run into similar issues to you.